# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is not working, the page received is blank

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to fetch certain websites via cURL and print them on screen. However some sites which do redirect the visitors are not being fetched successfully,In phpinfo() I confirmed that safe mode and basedir are not set. Following is my code:

```
<p> The download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">20 </span> Seconds</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var timeleft = 20;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
if(timeleft <= 0)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
},1000);
</script>
     <?php
     header( "refresh:20;url=index.php" );
            $ch2 = curl_init(); 
            $url = "https://youtube.com";
            $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)';
            $url = @str_ireplace("https://","http://",$url);
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            //return the transfer as a string 
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            // $output contains the output string 
            echo $output2 = curl_exec($ch2); 
            curl_close($ch2);   
    ?>
```

When i comment the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION line, the requested URL throws 301 error.

The second thing is, those pages which do not redirect the visitors and successfully get fetched by my codes, are not properly printed on screen.
 the website should be printed like the below image.[Original Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taasi.jpg)

But instead it is being printed like the below image: [The page fetched by my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQaqd.png)

This rendering problem persists with all websites and not just with the one whose screenshot i have uploaded.

SO, i want to solve:
1. The improper rendering of pages.
2. Unable to fetch and print the webpages which redirect the visitors.

ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have in mind that you cannot just copy the response of the URL and run the same webpage locally. There are tons of dependent files - styles, scripts and other which are not fetched with that. Any relative URL in the webpage will automatically be broken, because you don't have that file locally.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what problem you're trying to solve with this, but you might have better luck displaying the remote content in an iframe/etc. Otherwise, at the very least, you're going to have to re-write a lot of the HTML source, and will probably still end up with a lot of hard-to-find usability issues.

Comment: @vuryss but still the pages that do redirect must be fetched and printed on screen without proper formatting and rendering, atleast a single text from the site should be fetched, but all i get is a blank page, with not even a single character in it.

Comment: @iainn how can i do that? will this solve the problem of the redirect pages not being fetched?

Comment: @i just want to fetch websites like google and youtube, with proper formatting and rendering.

Comment: You cannot load Google and YouTube locally. Regarding the redirect - you adding a curlinfo - inspect the returned headers and body. There you should be able to see what's wrong. If you still can't post the exact response headers and body here so we can see the problem.

Comment: @vuryss if loading google or youtube through cURL is not possible, what do websites like 10khits.com do, to fetch and display all kinds of websites with proper formatting and rendering?

Comment: Oh man. Modern website are dynamic, they use tons of scripts and generate content on the fly after the page is loaded. Unless you use some JavaScript engine like V8 or whatever you cannot display a dynamic website. It's not entirely impossible, but it will take forever to do. Later there are other problems like domain restriction of certain services, internal requests to their APIs and so on. If you go back 20-30 years it might be possible to do that on some of the websites easily. Now unless the webpage is pure HTML/CSS - it's not that simple.

Comment: @vuryss this is what i'm getting in response header [link](https://imgur.com/zNhWSim)